# Showing safari browsing webpages history animation in iphone

Tags: iphone

i need to show the images from left to right on my view controller like we scroll web pages in safari browser...has anyone developed this thing...
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

this might help you..

```
 UIScrollView * scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]init];

for(int i=0;i<imageCount;i++)
{
 UIImageView *tempView=[[UIImageViewalloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((i*60),05,60,70)];
 tempView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"images.jpg"];
 [scrollView addSubview:tempView]; 
} 

    scrollView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 80);
scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(60*imageCount,70);
    scrollView.delegate=self;
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```